# HTML email not showing full width on android email

Tags: android, html, email, zooming

I have a HTML email that uses tables and no styling which can be viewed fine on an iphone and other email programs, but on an Android phone, it shows zoomed in and you can't pinch to zoom out on it.

Is there anyway I can force the email program to view full screen and allow zoom out?

Answer (score 1):

I take it the email is created with inline CSS and tables,

Desktops like the width to be in % in order to cover the entire width, and Apple products adjust to that, however Android needs to be in px. Try this:

```
<body style='width:100%; min-width:600px; ' >....</body>
```

Additionally for reference an article based on optimizing email designs for Android devices?

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3638/why-cant-i-get-my-html-email-to-look-great-on-android-devices

Answer (score 0):

The solution above does not work in all cases.
We have seen many different solutions around the web like for example declare the viewport meta such as :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

or the body :

```
<body style='width:100%; min-width:600px; ' >
```

He did not work for us on simple emailing.

Another solution will be to put table inside TD every time your want to create a new row such as and set the td width a 600px width :
    
     
    
    
    
    --- YOUR CONTENT ---

This one seems to be a bit annoying for us.

The solution that did work for us in all cases is to wrap the content of ALL your email within a td with a specified width of 600px and to display it as a block, like this :

```
<table width="600" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="600" style="min-width:600px;display:block;">
--- HERE GOES YOUR EMAILING STARTING WITH A TABLE ---
<table>
<tr>
<td> HELLO THIS MY EMAIL</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```